# Calling batch file from SQL CLP Script

Tags: sql, batch-file, db2

Hi I need to run a batch file from a sql-clp script:

The script is

```
 CONNECT TO MYTAB1 USER xxxx using yyyyyyy;
 QUIESCE DATABASE IMMEDIATE FORCE CONNECTIONS;
 CONNECT RESET;
 BACKUP DATABASE MYTAB1 TO "C:\temp\bcks" WITHOUT PROMPTING;
 CONNECT TO MYTAB1 USER xxxx using yyyyyyy;
 UNQUIESCE DATABASE;
 CONNECT RESET;
 cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\backup_neu.bat C:\temp\bcks C:\temp\bcks\zips 7z");
```

It runs great until it reaches the last line.
I tried

```
 cmd.exe /c 
 exec(' xp_cmdshell ''script_here'); 
 EXEC master..xp_CMDShell '"script here "'
```

but nothing worked.

OI have DB2 v10 running.

Any ideas on how I can get the batch file running?

Thanks for all your help.

TheVagabond

Comment: What does happen on the last line?

Comment: DB21034E  I got it in german it says something like, not a real SQL statement and therefore is being ignored.

SQL1024N Connection lost.  SQLSTATE=08003

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution....

really simple somehow, just needed

```
!C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\backup_neu.bat C:\temp\bcks C:\temp\bcks\zips 7z
```

so only a ! that was it.